# Convert Scapy time to time stamp string

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, datetime-format, scapy

```
>>> from scapy import *
>>> for pkt in pkts:
...     print pkt.time
...
1343551962.73
1343551963.28
1343551963.28
```

How can I convert that to YY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS ?